# Getting the standard errors right in a regression with many groups fixed effects in R

Tags: r, panel

I have a large dataset and I need to run a regression with three group fixed effects at once. With two groups all went fine using the `felm`command from the `lfe` package in R, but with three groups I get an error message saying that standard errors should be slightly too high, and apparently there is no solution to this problem. I was wondering if anyone knew of another package to avoid this issue? Also, the last dummies I need are not that many, so they are includable in a possible regression, but trying that doesn't solve it because I get another error about the matrix not being positive definite.

Any clues?